# Multithreading in action script using Worker Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

My main Thread is getting suspended, I'm new to action script.
what can be the reason for this error.

```
 Main Thread (Suspended: VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.system::Worker   could not be found.)
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of Flash Builder are you using, and which version of the SDK are you using to build your project?

Comment: @Brian :I'm using  Adobe® Flash® Builder™ 4.6

Answer (score 0):

This error is regarding the worker process not getting initialized. Try to update the flash player to latest version and flash builder if you are using it.

Please check this link for more 
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1037293

Answer (score 0):

If you had problem to use or implement `Workers` I made a lib to help this, and if you want you can contribute.. Just check in GitHub [ASWorker Link](https://github.com/Tavernari)

The implementation is like this

```
package
{
    import com.tavernari.asworker.ASWorker;
    import com.tavernari.asworker.notification.NotificationCenter;
    import com.tavernari.asworker.notification.NotificationCenterEvent;

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class ASWorkerDemo extends Sprite
    {
        private var asWorker:ASWorker;

        //BOTH AREA

        public function ASWorkerDemo()
        {
            //important know, all class start here will be replicated in all works.
            asWorker = new ASWorker(this.stage, uiWorkerStartedHandler, backWorkerStartedHandler);  
        }

        //BOTH AREA END

        //UI AREA START
        private function uiWorkerStartedHandler():void{
            //implement all class or calls for your UI

            NotificationCenter.addEventListener("FROM_BACK_EVENT_MESSAGE", onFromBackEventMessageHandler );

        }

        private function onFromBackEventMessageHandler(e:NotificationCenterEvent):void
        {
            trace(e.data);

            if(e.data == "completed job"){
                NotificationCenter.dispatchEventBetweenWorkers( new NotificationCenterEvent("NEXT_MESSAGE") );
            }
        }

        //UI AREA END

        //BACK AREA START

        private function backWorkerStartedHandler():void{
            //implement all class or calls for your BACK operations 
            NotificationCenter.addEventListener("NEXT_MESSAGE", uiCallForNextMessageHandler );
        }

        private function uiCallForNextMessageHandler():void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < 15; ++i){
                NotificationCenter.dispatchEventBetweenWorkers( new NotificationCenterEvent("FROM_BACK_EVENT_MESSAGE", false, i) );
            }

            NotificationCenter.dispatchEventBetweenWorkers( new NotificationCenterEvent("FROM_BACK_EVENT_MESSAGE", false, "completed job") );
        }

        // BACK AREA END
    }
}
```

Good luck with Workers